# Warning: mysql_real_escape_string(): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) .../public_html/checklogin.php

Tags: php, html, mysql

Thank you guys for the wonderful job you are doing. I just uploaded my website on the the remote server and it brought me back this error message.

```
Warning: mysql_real_escape_string(): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /home/therealimage/public_html/checklogin.php on line 3

Warning: mysql_real_escape_string(): A link to the server could not be established in /home/therealimage/public_html/checklogin.php on line 3

Warning: mysql_real_escape_string(): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /home/therealimage/public_html/checklogin.php on line 4

Warning: mysql_real_escape_string(): A link to the server could not be established in /home/therealimage/public_html/checklogin.php on line 4

Warning: mysql_connect(): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /home/therealimage/public_html/checklogin.php on line 6
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

This is my code:

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;

    INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `username`, `password`) VALUES
(1, 'charles', 'dove'),
(2, 'Editor', 'admin'),
(3, 'Night', 'owl');
```

my **checklogin.php** file

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password]);

    mysql_connect("50.28.8.6", "root","") or die(mysql_error()); //Connect to server
    mysql_select_db("therealimage_admin2015") or die("Cannot connect to database"); //Connect to database
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * from users WHERE username='$username'"); //Query the users table if there are matching rows equal to $username
    $exists = mysql_num_rows($query); //Checks if username exists
    $table_users = "";
    $table_password = "";
    if($exists > 0) //IF there are no returning rows or no existing username
    {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) //display all rows from query
        {
            $table_users = $row['username']; // the first username row is passed on to $table_users, and so on until the query is finished
            $table_password = $row['password']; // the first password row is passed on to $table_users, and so on until the query is finished
        }
        if(($username == $table_users) && ($password == $table_password)) // checks if there are any matching fields
        {
                if($password == $table_password)
                {
                    $_SESSION['user'] = $username; //set the username in a session. This serves as a global variable
                    header("location: home.php"); // redirects the user to the authenticated home page
                }

        }
        else
        {
            Print '<script>alert("Incorrect Password!");</script>'; //Prompts the user
            Print '<script>window.location.assign("login.php");</script>'; // redirects to login.php
        }

    }
    else
    {
        Print '<script>alert("Incorrect Username!");</script>'; //Prompts the user
        Print '<script>window.location.assign("login.php");</script>'; // redirects to login.php
    }
?>
```

Comment: You're failing to connect to the database. The credentials you're passing in `mysql_connect` are wrong.

Comment: apart from the mysql_connection paramaters, you have a lot of syntax errors in you code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Warning: mysql\_real\_escape\_string() \[function.mysql-real-escape-string\]: Access denied for user 'ODBC'@'localhost' (using password: NO)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33060622)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you use `mysql_real_escape_string()` function first then you connect:

```
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);

mysql_connect("50.28.8.6", "root","") or die(mysql_error()); //Connect to server
```

Solution is to connect first then use function `mysql_real_escape_string()`

```
//Connect to server
mysql_connect("50.28.8.6", "root","") or die(mysql_error()); 
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
```

This is because `mysql_real_escape_string()` requires the connection.

Comment: Yep, and I see you fixed the OP's missing quote in `$_POST['password]`. Now OP is asking more questions and yet to accept any, *tsk tsk*. Oh well, what can you do. Happy New Year btw, ;-) Cheers Edit: and even reposted http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33313656/connecting-with-database

Comment: @Fred-ii- how are you brother? Happy holidays to you and your family. Hope all is well freddy!

Comment: Pretty good, thanks. All is well and hope for you too. Happy Holidays to you and yours also, *cheers!*

Answer (score 0):

You probably forgot to supply correct username and password to connect to MySQL server. Here `mysql_connect("50.28.8.6", "root","")`

Answer (score 0):

Or you don't have remote acces privileges on you mysql servers user. Simply change localhost to % will grant root access to public network. Don't forget to flush privileges.

Comment: Thanks bro, i initially used MySQL_connect("localhost", "root","") or die(mysql_error()); but it doesn't work still.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. It move has moved me a bit further. Now i have change localhost to % but i got this: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$username' (T_VARIABLE), expecting ']' in /home/doesnews/public_html/checklogin.php on line 8. Please help? Thanks.