# Connecting with database

Tags: html, mysql, css

I am stuck and don't know what to do. I have issue connecting with my MySQL. I am using the information provided for me through Cpanel because I know that root password is only for the server admin and i am using shared hosting and can not get that . I have also give all privileges to the user even though I know I will change this once I got hold of this issue. my codes for connecting database are
**dbconnect.php:**

```
<?php
if(!mysql_connect("localhost","doesnews_users",""))
{
    die('oops connection problem ! --> '.mysql_error());
}
if(!mysql_select_db("doesnews_editor"))
{
    die('oops database selection problem ! --> '.mysql_error());
}

?>
```

this is what i got in response:

> Warning: mysql_connect(): Access denied for user
>   'doesnews_users'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in
>   /home/doesnews/public_html/dbconnect.php on line 2 oops connection
>   problem ! --> Access denied for user 'doesnews_users'@'localhost'
>   (using password: NO)

and this is my **register.php:**

```
<?php
session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['user']) != "")
{
header("Location: home.php");
}

include_once 'dbconnect.php';

if (isset($_POST['btn-signup']))
{
$uname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['uname']);
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$upass = md5(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pass']));
if (mysql_query("INSERT INTO users(username,email,password) VALUES('$uname','$email','$upass')"))
{
?>
        <script>alert('successfully registered ');</script>
        <?php
}
  else
{
?>
        <script>alert('error while registering you...');</script>
        <?php
}
}

?>
```

Comment: make sure you have right host name instead of localhost, because you are using shared hosting so it couldn't be localhost. it may be different.

Comment: Please don't repost and spamming Stack with questions where you really need to get a grasp as to how MySQL and PHP work and its syntax. Find out how "debug" code, something you are not doing at all.

Answer (score 0):

in your cpanel you should be able to see the db settings
host,username

you could also edit your db settings in case you forgot your password

another option is to check your mail, most of the time when creating a new database the hosting company sends you information on how to connect to your db.

Check the help from the hosting company, they usually also provide details on how to connect.